# Is there a function where the average over a set is equal to the value for that set's average?

Tags: functions, recurrence-relations

Using mathematical notation, my question is if there are any functions $f$ where $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i)=f\left(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right)$ for all sets $x=[x_1,x_2,...,x_n]$?

From that definition I was also able to find an identity for subtraction
$$f(x)-f(y)=z$$
$$f(x)+f(y)=z+2f(y)$$
$$2f\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)=z+2f(y)$$
$$2f\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)-2f(y)=z.$$
Repeating the process seems to generally give the identity
$$f(x)-f(y)=2^n\left(f\left(\frac{x+(2^n - 1)y}{2^n}\right)-f(y)\right).$$

In one attempt I tried using the basic definition of differentiation and the aforementioned identities to create a interesting differential equation, but worked myself into a situation I don't think can be developed.

<s>In another attempt, I noted that if every element of $x$ is equal any function trivially satisfies the addition-based identity. From there I thought to analyze the subtraction identity for $x=y$. From that I found that $f(x)=f\left(2x-2^{-k}x\right)$, which seems to imply $f$ must be periodic in some way. I'm not sure how to analyze the equation further, though.</s>

Any more insight into what properties $f$ might have or if exists would be greatly appreciated, thanks and take care.

**Edit**: Jonah points out a simple solution, $f(x)=ax+b$, is there a way to find a general form for all solutions or prove that a linear equation is the only one? Also, there was an error the first subtraction identity I provided. It has been fixed and the related text has been crossed out.

Comment: $f(x)=ax+b$ seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is defined on the set $\Bbb R$ of reals and continuous, then the example given above is the  set of all solutions. If $f$ is arbitrary, the *general solution* solution is of the form $f=\alpha+b$ where $\alpha$ is additive ($\alpha(x+y)=\alpha(x)+\alpha(y)$) and not necessarily continuous.
This may be seen as follows.
Using the property of $f$  we see that also $g:=f-f(0)$ has this property. Then using $x_1=x, x_2=\ldots=x_n=0$ results in $\frac1n g(x)=g(\frac1n x)$ since $g(0)=0$. Using this for $x_1+\ldots+x_n$ on the right hand side in the defining property of $f$ and $g$ we get $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n g(x_i)=g\left(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right)=\frac1n g\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right)$. With $x_3=\ldots=x_n=0$ we see that $g$ is additive. Thus $f=\alpha+b$ with $\alpha:=g$ and $b:=f(0)$. Moreove it is wellknown that all continuous additive functions are linear. Thus in this case there is some real $a$ such that $\alpha(x)=ax$ for all $x$.